# How can I subscribe to an event listener on add-sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Right now I'm developing an add-on for firefox 26 and I need to know if there is an event that keeps listening all the time when we are browsing the web even if there a script running, and if the event has a kind of trigger when you reach a specific url and How can I use it?
Por example I want to do something similar to the FoxyProxy add-on. The foxyproxy kept listening until it reaches a URL which redirects to a port or other ... how can I subscribe to that event, I'm new at this, please help me... 
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the sdk/system/events/ module. 
For example:

```
let { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");
let events = require("sdk/system/events");

events.on("http-on-examine-response", afterLoad);

function afterLoad(e) {

    var httpChannel = e.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel); 
    var url = httpChannel.URI.spec;

    // do what you want with the url
    console.log("Loaded: "+url);
}
```

The full list of events you can listen for is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds to me like you want to look at the tabs module in the Add-on SDK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html

The simplest implementation would look like:

```
require('sdk/tabs').on('ready', function(tab) {
    // do something here
    console.log(tab.url);
});
```

For more guides on how to use the SDK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html